# Why Consecutive days are not public?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privacy, consecutive-days

I can see consecutive days on my profile only. Also, without login I cannot see consecutive days on my profile. Why it is not available for public?

I am using Stack Overflow developer story as my resume. If visited and consecutive days are available for public view then it will be helpful (I didn't used it, I am not sure, I thought) for my clients & recruiters.

[image: screenshot from profile]

Comment: I don't know why a recruiter or prospective hiring manager would *care* how many consecutive days you've been on Stack Overflow.  You already have over 1,000 reputation.  That's been "enough" in most recruiters' and hiring managers' eyes.

Comment: A muuuuch better number is **~1.6m people reached**, congrats!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why Consecutive days are not public?

Because this is private information that the public at large has no business in knowing.

I can only imagine some boss or client spying on this info and going for your jugular *"What the heck have you been doing for more then 365 consecutive days on that site instead of getting your work done?"*.

> it will be helpful (I didn't used it, I am not sure, I thought) for my clients & recruiters

Maybe this part of your questioning could be a good fit for [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Interesting questions on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Record for most consecutive days visited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143842/185667)
- [Please add an “Über-Fanatic” badge!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58404/185667)

Comment: `What the heck have you been doing for more the 365 consecutive days on that site instead of getting your work done?` => This is common question If I did not complete work. I working to satisfies client and boss. Their priority is their work to be complete for them money... Client expectation is getting work done only. Boss expectation is getting work done and same time them employees self development.. simple, If I not  satisfy peoples on my filed then I can't survive.

Comment: I'm positive that any good programmer may have working reasons to visit SO daily. I just don't think there's any good value on showing everybody "I've been logged on this site for 1000+ consecutive days". IMO, what this info says is "this person doesn't take weekends, holidays or vacations, is s/he ok?". Is there any big site on the Internet that shows this info? Not that I'm aware of...

Comment: lol.. Nice Info. Got a point and make this answer is acceptable. I didn't think about negative side :)

Answer (score -1):

The number of consecutive days a user has visited the site is of very little value. It is not a reliable metric for active participation.

Someone who takes one day off a week would always have a low consecutive count (no more than six in my simple example) which would not be representative of their high participation.

On the other hand, a day-visit only requires a single page hit during a 24-hour period.   And someone could conceivably, if they felt it was worth the effort, automate a browser to visit randomly every day to avoid the consecutive days visited counter from resetting to one.

Besides that, supposing we assume all visits are legit, then looking at the **Member for** and **visited N days** information gives an indication of the overall frequency a user visits the site. **EDIT**: Oops, the total number of days visited is not public either—I think you could make a stronger case for making that number public.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S No harm in asking. As your question is tagged `[feature-request]`, I'm simply providing feedback; and hopefully shed some light on the rationale of the site design. I think this metric is mainly provided for our personal interest, especially those keen on the **enthusiast** and **fanatic** badges.